# Tomcat7 starts too late on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 [Digitalocean]

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, digital-ocean

i am using digitalocean and trying to install and start tomcat on ubuntu but unfortunately i can not do it. (created new droplets and tried 10 times)

***1GB Ram 30GB SSD Disk Amsterdam 2 Ubuntu 14.04 x64***

When i start tomcat, it says "Tomcat started". But i can not access page from browser. and ./shutdown.sh returns error.

What can be the problem ?

**I noticed something now. While i am writing this question, tomcat page is displayed. it took 28 minutes to display the page**

catalina.out says: **INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [1,718,769] milliseconds.**

Here are my installation steps (These steps works on different vps but doesn't work on digitalocean droplets):

Install oracle jdk

```
 sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
 sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
      java -version
      java version "1.7.0_72"
      Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
      Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

Set java path

```
      sudo nano /etc/environment
      JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"
      source /etc/environment
      wget http://ftp.itu.edu.tr/Mirror/Apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.56/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.56.tar.gz
      tar xvzf apache-tomcat-7.0.56.tar.gz
      mv apache-tomcat-7.0.56/ apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1/
```

Start Tomcat

```
        ./startup.sh
            Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1
            Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1
            Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1/temp
            Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
            Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
            Tomcat started.
```

Checkout Port 8080

```
        netstat -ln 
            tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
            tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN
            tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
            tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Checkout process

```
            ps -ef | grep tomcat
            root      2825     1  1 14:23 pts/0    00:00:03 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Open web site at port 8080 `http://5.101.107.56:8080/`  Page is waiting... [content is displayed after 28 minute or more]

Try to shutdown tomcat if content is not displayed yet (before tomcat starts properly).

```
      ./shutdown.sh 
            SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
            Oct 17, 2014 2:40:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
            SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
                java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSoc
```

Checkout logs

```
      catalina.out
            Oct 17, 2014 2:31:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
            INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
            Oct 17, 2014 2:31:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
            INFO: Initialization processed in 1492 ms
            Oct 17, 2014 2:31:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
            INFO: Starting service Catalina
            Oct 17, 2014 2:31:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
            INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
            Oct 17, 2014 2:31:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
            INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1/webapps/host-manager
```

I also installed nginx and navigate to `http://5.XXX.XXX.XX/` nginx welcome page is opened immediately

I checked catalina.out when i see the page in browser, it says:

```
    Oct 17, 2014 2:31:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56-server-1/webapps/host-manager
    Oct 17, 2014 3:00:27 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
    INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took **[1,718,769] milliseconds.**
```

Memory:

```
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:       1017912     849512     168400        332      18780     688468
```

Comment: Looks like the machine is running out of entropy for the random number generator.

Comment: yes, i am tryig to set -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Replacing `securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom` with `securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom` in `$JAVA_PATH/jre/lib/security/java.security` has solved my problem.

Even when `file:/dev/urandom` is specified, JRE will still use `/dev/random` for SHA1PRNG (see bug [JDK-4705093](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4705093)):

> In SHA1PRNG, there is a SeedGenerator which does various things
> depending on the configuration.
>
> 1. If java.security.egd or securerandom.source point to "file:/dev/random" or "file:/dev/urandom", we will use
>    NativeSeedGenerator, which calls super() which calls
>    SeedGenerator.URLSeedGenerator(/dev/random).  (A nested class within
>    SeedGenerator.)  The only things that changed in this bug was that
>    urandom will also trigger use of this code path.
> 2. If those properties point to another URL that exists, we'll initialize SeedGenerator.URLSeedGenerator(url).  This is why
>    "file:///dev/urandom", "file:/./dev/random", etc. will work.

From [Wikipedia on /dev/random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#Linux):

> In this implementation, the generator keeps an estimate of the number
> of bits of noise in the entropy pool. From this entropy pool random
> numbers are created. When read, the /dev/random device will only
> return random bytes within the estimated number of bits of noise in
> the entropy pool. **/dev/random** should be suitable for uses that need
> **very high quality randomness** such as one-time pad or key generation.
>
> **When the entropy pool is empty, reads from /dev/random *will block*
> until additional environmental noise is gathered.** The intent is to
> serve as a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator,
> delivering output with entropy as large as possible. This is suggested
> for use in generating cryptographic keys for high-value or long-term
> protection.

Environmental noise?

> The random number generator gathers **environmental noise** **from device
> drivers and other sources** into an entropy pool. The generator also
> keeps an estimate of the number of bits of noise in the entropy pool.
> From this entropy pool random numbers are created.

**That means in practice, it’s possible to block tomcat for an unknown amount of time.**

Comment: first thanks, this costed me 8 hours of work. i thought it was me. Second, if u installed tomcat via `apt-get` the `$JAVA_HOME` is here `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`

Comment: Thanks. I am using JDK8 and instead of .../urandom I had .../random. I did change the random to urandom as well.

Comment: Great help; thanks. The 7-minutes startup is so misleading... CentOS 7 with java installed via `yum install java-1.8.0-devel` has `java.security` located in `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0/lib/security`.

Comment: I have a follow up question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383430/tomcat-takes-too-much-time-to-start-java-securerandom. Is it ok to do so in production? Will this have any impact on security (like Session ID becoming predictable)?

Comment: Many thanks. Like others have said, I've spend the better part of a day trying to figure this heinous problem out.

Comment: Is there something that works for Windows? Issue remains the same where TomEE startup takes longer in one of the Windows NT 6.2 environment.

Answer (score 17):

This also works:

> Actually, by setting the following in /etc/default/tomcat7, I was fine:
>
> JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"

Comment from :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431922/tomcat7-starts-too-late-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64-digitalocean/27250730#comment41509118_26431922

Comment: Is there something that works for Windows? Issue remains the same where TomEE startup takes longer in one of the Windows NT 6.2 environment.

Answer (score 13):

While using `/dev/urandom` as the source for entropy is a workaround that reduces the startup time for Tomcat, it is not a good idea because it can have unintended side effects.

Other components running in the Tomcat server (e.g. web applications) might depend on a securely initialized `SecureRandom` instance and there might be security issues when the entropy for the random numbers is not sufficient.

Actually, this is one of the reasons why using `/dev/urandom` does not work, but `/dev/./urandom` does. The SHA1PRNG heavily relies on a good seed. If the seed is not good, the random numbers are predictable. Therefore, the developer ensured that for this purpose `/dev/random` is used as the source of entropy, even if the JVM is configured to use `/dev/urandom`. There are two bug reports about this ([bug 1](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6202721), [bug 2](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4705093)).

So instead of changing the entropy source to `/dev/urandom`, one should rather make sure that `/dev/random` has enough entropy. If the system has a hardware RNG, installing `rng-tools` should do the trick. Otherwise, installing `haveged` provides a very good source of entropy that does not rely on a special hardware RNG to be present. In a virtual machine, `rng-tools` can use entropy from the host through a virtual hardware RNG. As an alternative to this, [EGD](http://egd.sourceforge.net/) could be used, but at the moment this software is not included in the Ubuntu repositories, so that it is bothersome to use it.

Comment: Thanks. I confirm that by installing `haveged` and not changing from `/dev/random` I fixed the tomcat startup time and also by looking at `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` it seems that entropy pool is full again.