# tomcat is running, but no page display

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

I just start to set up tomcat for Ubuntu server.

I have tried to run tomcat by "catalina.sh run", it logs "

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.218 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.218 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.28.0
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.218 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.219 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.2.0-16-generic
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.219 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.220 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.220 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_85-b01
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.226 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.226 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.226 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.227 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.228 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.229 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.229 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.230 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.230 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.231 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.33 using APR version 1.5.2.
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.231 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.274 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014)
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.521 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8088"]
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.560 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2002 ms
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
22-Nov-2015 08:54:04.735 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
```

"

I check "ps -ef | grep tomcat", it returns "

```
root     30577 30576  2 08:54 pts/0    00:00:04 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
demo     30600 30491  0 08:57 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
```

"

"netstat -ln | grep 8088", it returns "
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN
"

does this mean that the tomcat is running?

if so, why I can't open the url with ip_address:8088? 
last night I can see the tomcat page with url ip_address:8088. This morning, I shutdown the tomcat by "shutdown.sh run", it returns "

```
Using CATALINABASE: /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINAHOME: /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINATMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JREHOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH: /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
usage: java org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina [ -config {pathname} ] [ -nonaming ] { -help | start | stop }
```

"

then I start tomcat by "catalina.sh run", the same log as I post above, when I try to access the ip_address:8088, the page is keeping running,but nothing display out. It has been 2 hrs, the page tag is still running, nothing displayed out. I didn't do anything after last night I see the tomcat page showed up.

then I tried to shutdown the tomcat with "shutdown.sh run", it returns "

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
usage: java org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina [ -config {pathname} ] [ -nonaming ]  { -help | start | stop }
Nov 22, 2015 11:07:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8006. Tomcat may not be running.
Nov 22, 2015 11:07:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:450)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:400)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:487)
```

"

Can anyone tell me why is that happen? and what should I do?

Comment: when I come back afternoon, I found the page ip_address:8080. Does this mean my tomcat took so long (several hours) to start up?  It must not be normal, can anyone help me?

Comment: sorry, it's ip_address:8088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat should start up in seconds, especially if you've just downloaded and unzipped it.

I'd suggest checking the running tomcat processes and killing them first. From the output from your shutdown command, it doesn't look like it was shutdown cleanly (note the "usage" feedback -- use either `./shutdown.sh` or `./catalina.sh stop`).

Next, check the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml`. It seems like you may have been changing the default ports. `8080` is the default port for Tomcat, not `8088` (and `8005` is the default shutdown port, not `8006`) so make sure you have these set the way you want before you start the server.

I'd definitely recommend reading through the documentation also http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt

Comment: Hi Jason, I download tomcat 7, just try to check if tomcat run. I only unzip it on /opt/tomcat_7 folder, then I run "catalina.sh run" to start up tomcat, but the log shows it stuck at "INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat_7/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/webapps/ROOT",  and it takes a lot of time (hours of time). I only keep "ROOT" in webapps.

Comment: Try the workarounds mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431922/tomcat7-starts-too-late-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64-digitalocean