# Spring Boot not starting on Digital Ocean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, digital-ocean

I have a Droplet running Ubuntu with Java JDK 1.8 installed. I have transferred my spring boot fat jar. I can execute it no problems on my local machine. On Digital Ocean, it hangs as seen below indefinitely. I just upgraded the memory from 512MB to 1GB and same issue.

```
2016-09-02 22:02:13.010  INFO 2529 --- [           main] com.example.Application                  : Starting Application v1.0-SNAPSHOT on restfulProducts with PID 2529 (/home/aaron/restApp/springboot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by aaron in /home/aaron/restApp)
2016-09-02 22:02:13.022  INFO 2529 --- [           main] com.example.Application                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-09-02 22:02:13.250  INFO 2529 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@736e9adb: startup date [Fri Sep 02 22:02:13 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-02 22:02:16.880  INFO 2529 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$41018882] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-09-02 22:02:18.233  INFO 2529 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-09-02 22:02:18.280  INFO 2529 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-09-02 22:02:18.283  INFO 2529 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
2016-09-02 22:02:18.512  INFO 2529 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-09-02 22:02:18.512  INFO 2529 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5271 ms
2016-09-02 22:02:18.948  INFO 2529 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-09-02 22:02:18.957  INFO 2529 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-02 22:02:18.958  INFO 2529 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-02 22:02:18.958  INFO 2529 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-02 22:02:18.958  INFO 2529 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26432537/4516887

Answer (score 0):

Fateddy's suggestion did not work, however it identified the correct problem; low entropy. The https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged which uses haveged worked perfectly.