# Cannot connect to tomcat server

Tags: linux, tomcat, servlets, ubuntu-server

I am trying to install tomcat in a Ubuntu Server machine.

At first i installed tomcat8 through `apt-get` and i was able to connect. Then i tried to add some webapps for [dspace](http://dspace.org/), and from the time i added them, i cannot connect to the 8080 port. I removed the webapps and still i couldn't connect.

I already tried to reinstall tomcat, then i manually installed tomcat and i also tried tomcat 7 and 9, but i couldn't resolve my problem.

I tried to change the port, and I had the same problem. Also there are no other programs using this port.
I tried apache server at port 8080 and it works, so there shouldn't be a problem with my provider or firewall.

Also, the catalina.out log doesn't have any warnings.

Any ideas before I make a fresh install of the Server?

Answer (score 0):

Just minutes after i posted this, the server responded to the browser after 10 minutes waiting.

I found this solution and it worked

[Tomcat7 starts too late on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 [Digitalocean]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431922/tomcat7-starts-too-late-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64-digitalocean)