# Spring boot authentication only works sometimes on Google Cloud

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, google-cloud-platform

I have a tutorial i am following for Spring Security.
Although the login woks well on localhost, after i deploy it to google cloud, Spring security login only works sometimes. For example, when i press login, sometimes it gets the login?error sometimes it doesn't.

I am very confused about this behaviour.

I have tried adding cutom authentication, but it hasn't worked. Even when i enter a 4 letter username, I either get nothing (login page refreshes) or logs in (but just 1 in 10 attempts).

If you were to test this in localhost it would work perfectly fine.
Although : http://website-live-245110.appspot.com/ (gccloud hosted site) here it does not always work.

CustomAuthenticationProvider.java

```java
package com.spring.authprovider;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

    @Autowired
    private ThirdPartyAuthProviderClient thirdPartyAuthProviderClient;

    // one a user logs in, the authentication variable is filled with the details of the authentication
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // when the user logs in to the application, our object will be filled by spring
        String name = authentication.getName();
        Object password = authentication.getCredentials(); //object that encapsulates password that user types 
        // not printing or storing password anyone

        if(thirdPartyAuthProviderClient.shouldAuthenticate(name,password)) {
            // the array list is for roles, because we are not using it now, we are sending it an empty one
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            System.out.println("authentication failed for user: " + name);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        // there are multiple ways of authentication, use use username and password
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

ThirdPartyAuthProviderClient.java

```java
package com.spring.authprovider;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ThirdPartyAuthProviderClient {

    //emulates request to third party application
    public boolean shouldAuthenticate(String username, Object password) {
        // 3rd party request to see if user is correct or no or should be logged in
        // user with username with 4 digits can be logged in to the application
        return username.length() == 4;
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```java
package com.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

import com.spring.authprovider.CustomAuthenticationProvider;



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home", "/time").permitAll() // any request matching /, /home, /time
                                                                                // can be accessed by anyone
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // any other request needs to be authenticated
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**") // only admin can access /admin/anything
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login") // permit all to form login--- we use loginPage to use custom page
                .permitAll()
                .and().logout() // permit all to form logout
                .permitAll();

    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //specify auth provider
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    // configuration of static resources
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/templates/**", "/assets/**");
    }
}
```

MvcConfig.java

```java
package com.spring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

**Templates**

hello.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 th:inline="text">Hello [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]!</h1>
        <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

home.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>

        <p>Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to see a greeting.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect it to either log me in when a username with 4 characters is entered, Or output Invalid username and password. Error. 
Code is here : https://github.com/jeffpascal/Spring-and-springboot/tree/devs/SpringSecurity

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar kind of issue.  My Spring-Security application used to worked perfectly fine on local system, but when I deployed it on Google cloud, authentication wasn't working.

I used to get login page but when I click login button, response never came to my browser.

I added debug logs, can see in hibernate's show-sql logs that user is getting retrieve from DB but then nothing further.

After keeping application up and running for couple of mins more, I saw following log

> INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [260,620] milliseconds.

Then I modified `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`, changed line `securerandom.source=file:/dev/random` to `securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom`.

For more details on why this worked, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431922/tomcat7-starts-too-late-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64-digitalocean/26432537#26432537) or [this](https://blog.longyb.com/2019/06/09/tomcat_hang_creation_of_securerandom_instance_for_sessionid_english/)